# Can a conditional sentence begin with "when"?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, sentence-starts

I would want to dispel my doubts about the grammaticality of the following sentence:

- *When Andrew is there, he will probably have to be helped to climb the stairs.*

Some context: I know for certain that Andrew will go there, but I am not sure he will need help.

Is this a conditional sentence? If so, must the dependent clause begin with “if” instead of “when”? And, if I remove “probably”, is the sentence no longer conditional?

Comment: **Please edit your question** to *precisely define ᴇxᴀᴄᴛʟʏ* what you mean by “conditional sentence”. Do you perhaps mean the following?  ❶ A *declarative sentence* is a clause containing a subject and a predicate expressed with a finite verb.
❷ A *statement* is a declarative sentence.
❸ A ***conditional statement/sentence*** is a statement that relates two other statements, P and Q, such that “If P then Q”. (FYI: In a conditional statement of the form “If P then Q”, P is called the *hypothesis*
and Q is called the *conclusion*. Grammarians also call P the *prolepsis* and Q the
*apodosis*.)

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by [Robusto](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto):

It's not a conditional, since *when* expresses certainty that Andrew will be there. The fact that there is only a probability that he will need help **when he is there** does not alter the certainty as stated.

Answer (score 0):

#### “if” does not always express a hypothetical. When it doesn’t, you can sometimes use “when”.

There are uses of “if” that are used to state simple cause-and-effect relationships, or for emphasis, for example:

- “if you light a match, you get a flame”

This is known as the [zero conditional](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/zero-conditional/). The condition is always true. The other types of conditional sentences (first, second third) that use “if” describe hypothetical situations of decreasing likelihood (e.g., a third conditional form is one where the condition is known to be false, e.g. “if I had read this text carefully before submitting it, I would not have posted it”).

The thing about these these zero-conditional “if” statements, is that they can sometimes be re-written using “when” without change of meaning. For example:

- “if you run all day, you get tired”
- “when you run all day, you get tired”

These are semantically identical, although many grammar textbooks will tell you that grammatically only the one with “if” is a conditional sentence. (A helpful simplification, but there are types of conditionals that don’t even use “if”: such as “were you to find yourself in disagreement with this statement, you would add a polite comment")

Not all of the can be swapped for “when” versions: sometimes, zero conditionals are used to emphasise the finality of an event repeating the same clause, for example:

- *“if the dog needs to be fed, it needs to be fed”*
  There’s nothing you can do to avoid feeding the dog.

In this case, substituting “when” subtly changes the meaning of the sentence:

- *“when the dog needs to be fed, it needs to be fed”*
  The dog regularly needs feeding, and must be fed when it needs to be.

Comment: when the dog to be fed?

Comment: **What is a “conditional sentence”?** I see both the condition to be met and its result when true. How then is this ***not*** a conditional statement of the form “If P then Q”? Note that neither the ordering of the clauses nor the spelling of those words *if* and *then* matters to the formal requirements of logic. You can say *If the sky is blue then the sun is up*, or you can say *When the sky is blue then the sun is up*, or you can say *The sun is up when the sky is blue.* The hypothesis is whether the sky is blue; its conclusion is that the sun is up. How is this not a conditional sentence?

Comment: Bah. I posted this accidentally, before I had a chance to re-read, do some checking and fix the examples to make sense. Hope it reads better now.